# Check if an already retrieved element with Selenium has a specific class

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, try-catch

With selenium I'm getting and element:

```
element = section.find_element_by_tag_name('header')
```

The `header` element can have a class `open` if is is opened(like an accordion).

If the element has the class `open` I do nothing(because is already opened and I don't want to close it) but if it is not opened I want to click on it:

```
 element.click()
```

What I don't know is how do I check if the retrieved element(`header`) has the class "open" or not.

Comment: I can't really get your second line, is it a typing mistake?

Comment: @P.hunter code line ? , not it is not

Comment: `if "open" in element.get_attribute("class"):` ?

Comment: no, not in the code, it is fixed now in the edit, by the way to your problem, you can just check the behavior of parent tag after the button is being clicked. like maybe it is getting dark, or maybe even changes in the attributes of your child elements, something like that? in short: you have to manually check what's going on when you click the accordion and then write the script according to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to check if the class equals `open` do nothing, else click on `header` element.

```
element = section.find_element_by_tag_name('header')
if 'open' not in element.get_attribute('class'):
    element.click()
```

Answer (score 1):

To invoke `click()` or do nothing depending on the presence of `class` attribute **open** you have to wrap up the logic in a `try-catch{}` block as follows:

```
try:
    section.find_element_by_xpath("//header[not(@class='open')]").click()
except NoSuchElementException:
    pass
```